# Java Card - Transfering ec public key from offcard to java card Applet

Tags: javacard

I'm trying to implement two way authentication flow for java card applet. Following is my approach.

1. Create EC (Eliptic curve) key pair for offcard applications.
2. Store the public key of the offcard application in the java card.
3. Sign input data from offcard application private key.
4. Verify it using offcard application public key stored in the java card applet.

I'm struggling at step two. All others seems trivial. I need to find a way to encode the public key created outside to card into byte array and then transfer that byte array to java card applet and reconstruct the public key and store it in the persistent memory.

Any hint on this.

Comment: Which JavaCard version do you use?

Comment: Java card 2.2.1, JCOP31 v2.4.1

Comment: Note that your last "accept" was on August 2012. Please accept answers so they can be seen as "answered", or indicate why they are not acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an APDU with the following command data:

1. a short with the key size (the size of the *order* N)
2. send all the parameters except G (the base point) and W (the public key) and H as statically sized octet string (or byte array, if you are used to Java)

   - strip initial byte set to `00` if present
   - left padded with zero's bytes until you get the key size
3. send the G and W as uncompressed points

   - one byte `04`
   - followed by both coordinates, sized using the method above
   - length is 2 times key size in bytes, plus one for the `04` indicator
4. optionally send the cofactor H as byte (but it's always `01` anyways)
5. use the `set...` methods to set the key

And presto, one EC key for you.

---

You can of course also parse a PKCS#8 EC key or use length indicators for each and every field, but this method is probably the most compact one.

Answer (score -4):

To Achieve this you have to create a Javacard applet which....something like below

```
class MyApplet extends javacard.framework.Applet
{
 // ...
 public void process(APDU apdu)
 {
  // ...
  byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
  //Other stuff
 }
}
```

To reach in `public void process(APDU apdu)` method you should select your applet with its AID after that every command will start reaching to this method.
You can create your own proprietary APDU to send "offcard application private key" and can get that here
`byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();` and then you can store it in a persistent array of your applet.

Comment: You explain how to send/receive APDU's. The question is not about that, even though sending / receiving APDU's is of course required to create EC keys from offcard data. The term "EC" is not even in your answer. Finally, you seem to indicate that the question was to send the private key, while actually the public key needed to be send.